# Prove that $f(z)$ is a onto group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given  $G= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} |  \exists \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \text{such that} \ z^n=1\}$.
Define a map $f : G \to G $ by  $$f(z)=z^k$$

where $k>1$ is fixed and $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

**My question** :  Prove that  $f(z)$ is  a onto group homomorphism ?

**My attempt**  : No , take  $z^{n/k} \in G$  now $f(z^{n/k})=z^n=1$  for all  $z^{n/k} \in G$

$\implies$  $f$ become  a  constant i,e  $f=1$

we know that constant function never give onto

therefore  $f$ is not a onto homomorphism

Comment: Your solution is extremely unclear. How do you use $n$ here? In the definition of $G$, $n$ is just a variable-for every $z\in G$ there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (which depends on $z$) such that $z^n=1$. It is not a constant number.

Comment: It is also not obvious what $z^{n/k}$ means if $k \not \mid n$. Also, nitpicking: a constant function can be onto, if the set is a singleton :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that $n$ is not fixed ! For $z \in G$, *a priori*, the "corresponding $n$" could be anything.

A good idea to start would be to understand what the elements of $G$ look like. In fact, you can try to show (or may be you already know) that if $z^n = 1$, then you can write $z = e^{\frac{2ir\pi}n}$ for some $0 \leq r < n$.

This means that $G = \{e^{\frac{2ir\pi}n}\;|\; n \in \mathbb N^\ast , 0\leq r < n\}$. Now you can work out more precisely how your function acts on this set !

Answer (score 2):

From Numbra answer

Motive : to show  $f$ is onto

$G = \{e^{\frac{2ir\pi}n}\;|\; n \in \mathbb N^\ast , 0\leq r < n\}$.

Now let $f $ is given by $e^{\frac{2ir\pi}n} \in G \implies a=e^{\frac{2ir\pi}{kn}}\in G$

according to question  $f(a)=a^k=e^{\frac{2ir\pi}n}$

so  $f$ is onto